# Disable "Upcoming Alarm" Notification (without disabling alarm)

Tags: notifications, alarm, clock, google-pixel

I'm fairly new to the Android platform so hopefully this is a silly question, but since I've had my Pixel (Pixel 1, Android 8.0.0), it's been giving me notifications for alarms I set in the Clock app two hours prior to their occurrence (disregard actual time in the screenshot). Note that I *do not want to delete the alarm*, just this notification about it.

[image] .

I know this isn't a *huge* issue, but it's just more annoying notification clutter that I don't want. What's weird is, I've apparently found the settings to change this behavior - but the toggle is disabled and I can't modify it.

[image]

Is there another way to do this that I'm missing, or a way to enable that toggle?

Comment: What if you toggle the allow notifications to off. And anyway hope did you get to the second screen? Are you using Google clock, cuz i didn't find the notifications screen you're at.

Comment: @ A Bochur - that toggle controls the "allow notifications dot" setting which dictates if it shows the blue dot on the app icon if there's a notification (it took me a minute to notice the "dot" in there). I reached this screen by holding down the "upcoming alarm" notification and then selecting "all categories". I can provide a screenshot of that if it would be helpful.

Comment: (My bad, didn't see the dot.) Now, on my phone when i long press on the upcoming alarm notification, it bring up the default notifications settings asking if i wanna block notifications. Apparently on your phone it's different. Is it the same when you go to settings>apps>clock> notifications? If you're able to block it from there, the alarm will still sound but you will not have a notification about snoozing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending an hour on the phone with Google tech support (don't know why I didn't think of this earlier) their representative was able to replicate the issue.

At this time there appears to be no way to disable this notification on a stock/unrooted Pixel. I'll update the answer if I get any further information.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is a late response but I just ran across this as I am having the same problem. Thank to jszpila [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185636/96277) for posting Google's response so I didn't have to waste any more time trying to get rid of the "upcoming alarm" notification.

As a work-around, I changed the sound for the "upcoming alarm" notification to "None". The notification still comes up but it is unobtrusive.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 2):

A long press 'upcoming alarms' will bring up another screen where you can customize the 'upcoming alarms' notification category.

Comment: But it says "Notifications from this app can't be turned off".  And I found no way on that other screen to turn them off.

Comment: This one worked on Pixel 2 with Android 10!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it by setting an alarm and waiting for the notification to come up. Long press and go to more settings. Weirdly, as you said, it's already disabled, but if you tap on the bottom line with the disabled setting, you get a new menu and then select notification priority (the top option) and select "low priority".

Comment: Alas, this doesn't actually _disable_ the alarm; it just makes it less obtrusive.  Other things that pass along the notifications (like Microsoft Band) will pass along the pre-alarm alarms.  (I can selectively disable the Clock app from being allowed to send notifications to the Microsoft Band...but presumably that disables the actual alarms too, and not just the stupid pre-alarm alarms.)

Answer (score 2):

This is from a Mate 20 Pro with Android 9, and Google Clock app version 6.2.
It is now possible to disable the annoying notification.
For me, it was SO annoying, because I use a Garmin smartwatch that vibrates when a notification arrives, and it ended up waking me up 2 hours earlier!

[image: Clock app notifications settings] [image: the settings about next alarm notification]

[image: turned off the dreaded setting] [image: system details]

Sorry for the screenshots' language, it's in Italian which is my native language, but I hope that they can help.

Comment: I have Android 9 on the Pixel 3XL. I have the same issue with smartwatch waking me up 2 hrs early.   My settings for the Clock app look entirely different. Could you state exactly which setting you changed to disable the advance notification?

Comment: In Italian, it is "Orologio" -> "Prossime sveglie" -> "Consenti notifiche" -> Off. Screenshots show each page, one after the other, until the setting is set to Off.
Last screenshot shows the EMUI version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called "alarm skip" that lets you dismiss/turn off an alarm two hours before it rings.  I hadn't realized that I had turned it on, but I was missing alarms because of that notification (and dismissing it turns the alarm off).  I turned off Alarm Skip in settings, and things should work better now. Sharing in case someone else needs this.

(ETA: I'm on an LG V35 ThinQ so I don't think my phone is completely stock Android, but perhaps looking for some variation of this function will help you find the setting to turn it off?)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. The OP is trying to disable the alarm notification, not skip the alarm.

Comment: While not really addressing the original question, this answer would help me if it works (I've yet to test it)

Comment: Note: the question was specifically talking about the Google Clock app. Meanwhile, manufacturers may also customize their stock apps, thus this answer may only apply to LG's stock clock app.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, as I use a modified 7.1.2, but I got the impression you could disable individual, or at least app-wide notifications, by swiping to the side and tapping the settings button.

Also, in MM / N there's a menu somewhere in the notifications settings that let's you block notifications from an app, I know that for sure.  As I said before, I don't use Oreo, though if I found a ROM for my device that did, I would.

Let me know if this works, or if it doesn't.

Comment: @N 3 V 3 R A H T yeah, that's what gets me to the screen displayed in the second screenshot. The issue being that the toggle that would control that functionality is both on *and* disabled by default, so I can't change it.

Comment: Do you have power notifications enabled, or is that a Resurrection Remix only feature?  If not, go into notifications > the settings wheel in the right corner > Power Notification Controls and turn it on, assuming you have it.  If so, go to notifications > Clock, click on the A symbol under "importance", and set the bar next to it to the farthest left.

Again, keep in mind that I'm using a custom Nougat ROM, and that this might not exist on stock Oreo.

Comment: I would also suggest rooting and flashing a custom ROM anyways, it adds a ton of functionality to your device, especially if you like insane customization like me.  You can also do a lot more in terms of blocking things, and removing unnecessary system apps.

Comment: Rooting: https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel/how-to/guide-root-android-o-dev-preview-1-pixel-t3591548

I have to go, let me know what you've figured out, and tell me if I've helped at all.

Comment: I'm not totally against rooting but I've had trouble caused by carrier updates in the past, and it really seems like overkill for this situation. I'll do some reading on it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling notifications stopped the 2-hour-early reminder for me without affecting the alarms themselves.

Comment: Did you intend to reply to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185617/96277)? If not, consider mentioning how you disabled the notifications so that others can benefit more easily from your solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Install [AutoNotification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autonotification) which can be flexibly configured to block almost any notification.

Install the app.

1. Make sure the Upcoming Alarm notification is active (set an alarm for a few minutes time if not)
2. Open AutoNotification
3. Choose **Notification Blocking** in the **Standalone Features** section.
4. Touch the **+**
5. When asked for help setting up the block filter, Press **Yes**
6. If you have more than one notification active, it will ask you which one to use - tap on **Clock: Upcoming Alarm**.
7. Choose **Title** when asked about about Title or Text.
8. Press **OK** if it tells you about Partial Blocking.
9. The Filter setup screen should already be pre-populated with the right information, on my phone it looks like this:

[image]

10. Press **OK** and you're done - the Upcoming alarm notification should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial answer, after going to

https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079661?hl=en#contact=1

selecting the Samsung helpsite, and chatting with Pete.

He instructed me to go to Settings > Accessibility. At the top of the list was something that said "Using 2 functions". I was able to turn off the upcoming notification of notifications in Timely there.

The Timely timer still doesn't have any sound. (I've added "The Clock" to my list of apps to have a timer that rings.) Nudnik works, but it still doesn't unlock my screen. And I still haven't figured out how to turn off the damned bubbles that are cluttering up my screen.

But avoiding 25-minute advance notifications of notifications is progress, at least.

Comment: Note: the question was specifically talking about the Google Clock app. Thus, this answer may not apply to that app, but only to the mentioned apps on this particular answer.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is possible now with newer version of Android. I just wish they made the distinction between having the notification be available to see, but not "wake" the screen at 120 minutes and 30 minutes before the alarm.

I'd still like to see the upcoming alarm if I wake the screen manually, I just don't want it waking my screen twice on its own.

Disabling "Upcoming alarms" means everything goes away. Oh well.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.androidsage.com/2018/08/09/how-to-enable-system-ui-settings-on-any-android-device/

Install a System UI Tuner launcher, then go to Status Bar.  Scroll down to Alarm and turn off.  Now the Alarm icon will be hidden from the status bar.

Comment: This may hide the alarm icon on the status bar, but not preventing the notification itself.